# PHP - Load vars from file to php variables

Tags: php, parsing

I want to import variables from text file to PHP variables:
my txt file looks like this:

```
var1=80
var2=130
var3=250
```

and i want load them as variables in php like this:

```
<?php
$var1=80;
$var2=130;
$var3=250;
?>
```

I tried explode("=", $file); but that prints

```
Array ( [0] => var1 [1] => 80 var2 [2] => 130 var3 [3] => 250 )
```

EDIT:
I want output like this:

```
Array ( [var1] => 80 [var2] => 130 [var3] => 250 )
```

Comment: You're not splitting the file into lines. That's what you want to do first.

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 7):

```
$vars = parse_ini_file('filename');
extract($vars);
```

though I'd keep them in array, by omitting `extract()` part

Comment: + This is the way to do it.

Comment: <?php
$vars = parse_ini_file('vars.txt');
extract($vars);
print_r($vars);
?>

nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function for loading variables from external files.